# Excel Lookup/Search and Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get to the bottom of an issue I have been struggling with for days, in my example I have to match what is in column G to what is in column A whether it be a complete match or a partial match, then check that the Qty matches and pull across the Sal value.  My example works with an exception.  If an ID appears multiple times in my Lookup table but has different Qty, it only validates the last one in my reference table.  I have put this in to my attached example.

```
=IFERROR(IF(H2=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($A$1:$A$12,G2),$D$1:$D$12),LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($A$1:$A$12,G2),$C$1:$C$12),"Qty Issue"),"UnKnown ID")
```

I have this in an example file but unfortunately no way to upload it.

[image: Example Data]

[Download File](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoGai22pMzMRgSPD5AlHdZj_0A-k)

Comment: Could you at least provide some dummy sample data so we get an idea how your data is structured.

Comment: `LOOKUP()` is deprecated. Use `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Closest formula put to J2, as your expected K7 (60) and K11 (0) values has no logic

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$12,$A$1:$A$12,LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($A$1:$A$12,G2),$A$1:$A$12),$D$1:$D$12,H2)
```

**Syntax**

**LOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_vector, [result_vector])**

- If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function
  matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal
  to lookup_value.
- If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in lookup_vector,
  LOOKUP returns the #N/A error value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the look up value is there, hopefully you can see that from the image I have just added to the question.  Initially when the first record is found and the data is matched then the value is inserted correctly but when a second record is added to the lookup table but with a different Qty the previous value disappears but the new record gets the correct record.  Its like it can't do 2 checks when the ID's are the same and the Qty is different.

Comment: Can you attach your excel file?

Comment: I didn't think you could attach files on this site or am I wrong?

Comment: You can attach link to uploaded file

Comment: I've added a link to download my test file.

Comment: Why K7 expected 60? if it not exist at all? You trying lookup text within numbers? Also you trying search unsearcheable `5G12VA4369` within `5G12VA`

Comment: My apologies, K7 is showing the correct result "Qty Issue", though there is a part matching ID there is no matching code.  This was an oversight when removing some other testing.  In essence if I can find a partial match i.e. G12 to A10/A11/A12 but find a further match on the Qty in the case of G12 this would be A12 so the result Sal value I want to pull across is 288.

Comment: The amended code that you sent me almost assigned all the correct values but some are still being missed.  I have amended my example download to show that it assigns 5 records correctly but 3 are set to 0 even though they are looking at the same values.  What I have almost managed to do is on Sheet1 the original data that I will be doing the same work on but either sheet the issue is the same so its easier to work from the Data tab.